# sfdx scanner - Install problem

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, security-scanner

I have installed:-

Visual Studio Code Version 1.80.1 on Windows 11
"C:\Program Files\Java"   with directories: jdk-17.0.5  jdk-20 and jre-1.8

VS Terminal Command:   sfdx update completed successfully.

sfdx plugins install @salesforce/sfdx-scanner
Success:   @salesforce/sfdx-scanner... installed v3.14.0

VS Terminal Command:   sfdx scanner:run --format=csv --outfile=CodeAnalyserGeneral.csv --target="./" --category="Security"
resulting in Error:

"Warning: Deprecated config name: apiVersion. Please use org-api-version instead.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
ERROR running scanner:run:  The Java Home with directories  invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281. Error code: .
Please verify that Java 1.8 or later is installed on your machine and try again.
If the problem persists, please manually add a 'javaHome' property to your Config.json file, referencing your Java home directory."

Question:
Where is Config.json file (I am unable to find it.) and how to "reference your Java home directory" if found.

I would appreciate guidance, thank you

Comment: is java 1.8 or later installed on your machine?

Comment: Thank you for the response Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file it's referring to is the Config.json file for the code scanner in your user settings.
For Windows it will be in c:/users/username/.sfdx-scanner

Comment: Thank you Maz 44. I had worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Config.json" is a little misleading.
Following the link below for Java install was clear and successful.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_overview.htm